# Getting a list of Firebase databases I have access to

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have an Android app which uses a central Firebase Realtime DB, but there's also some other DB's that are used by other `flavors` of the app.

I want a central "admin" user of the main app, eg an Area Manager, to be able to switch and retrieve certain reports from the other databases. For example, the user is in Area "A" and has access to Database "A", but also has access to Database "A1" and "A3", but not "A2", then I want to be able to show these Databases in a list on the app for easy switching.

So is it possible to query Firebase and say "Give me a list of all Databases I have read access to."?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built into the regular Firebase client-side SDKs to get a list of projects. But using the REST API or Admin SDK you can get such a list. For example, by hitting `https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/availableProjects` as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/workflow_set-up-and-manage-project).

Unfortunately there is no official way to read the security rules for the Realtime Database through this API (yet). This [link in the API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firebaserules/) shows that it should be possible though.

If you go this route, keep a few things in mind:

- These are APIs that are only meant to be used from a trusted environment. So don't embed anything like this into an app that you distribute to your regular users.
- Some of the APIs used are in beta, and thus may change at any point without notice.
- The best you'll get are the rules themselves, not yet whether those grant you access to the database, as interpreting the rules is whole project on its own.
- You're working with the raw data that Firebase uses in many cases, which means you may have to do quite some digging to distill it into your use-case. As such, Christopher's answer may be a lot simpler to implement.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to query Firebase and say "Give me a list of all
>   Databases I have read access to"?

No, Firebase does not provide support out of the box to manage meta-security rules for access to multiple databases. Each database has its own security rules.

However, you could have a master database that stored information about which users had read or modify access to multiple databases.